# How to pass array through Ajax to server in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax

I wanted to send array to server and do check in nodejs code

```
function(project id){// Project id = [1,3,4,5] 
     var data : project id
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
         url: '/checkstatus',
         data: data,
    }).function(done){
         console.log(true);
    }
}
```

// Could you please correct the Ajax code and as well as how do you get input in req in server side. i want to run loop in server side.

Comment: Hey @kundan, this is the very common problem, probably you can follow some online tutorial to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achived this like this:

```
function(project id){// Project id = [1,3,4,5] 
     var data : project id
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
         url: '/checkstatus',
         data: JSON.stringify(data),//it will convert array to string
    }).function(done){
         console.log(true);
    }
}
```

And server side convert string to array like this.

```
let data = JSON.parse(req.body)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Narayan Sharma, could you please help me to write code in server side. i wanted to check jenkins Api wheather job is created or not for all project id. and get output in array or object for display in table in ui

Comment: exports.checkjob = function (req, res) {
     var data = req.body)  // req.body  { ' "1","3","4", 5" ': '  ' } 

     logger.debug(req.body);
    jenkins.view.exists(pipelineName, function (err, exists) {
             if (err) {
             res.send({ error: true, message: err.message });
             }
             res.send({ error: false, message: exists });           
        });
};

Comment: if you print that it will give you an array so loop through that array and do what ever you want to. If this helpful for you please mark this answer as correct. So that it will helpful for other too.